# celery schedule not working

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery and trying to run the **corntab**. Below is my celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery.schedules import crontab


from celery import Celery

app = Celery('Celery_1',
             broker='amqp://test:test@localhost//',
             include=['Celery_1.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'T1': {
        'task': 'Celery_1.tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': (4, 5)
}
},
    CELERY_IMPORTS = ('Celery_1.tasks', )

)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

And my tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from Celery_1.celery import app


@app.task(name='Celery_1.add')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

when i schedule by celery beat

[image]

but it is not running task for every minute. Can any one please help me ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How? I'm facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should run it this way (while still in the `Celery_1` directory):

`echo $null >> __init__.py #to make your directory a python project
cd ..
celery -A Celery_1 beat`

Celery_1 is the name of your app.